# Return Value from a Modal Dialog (IE + Safari)?

Tags: internet-explorer, safari, modal-dialog

The following works in IE, but how can I get it working in Safari?

My pop up script:

strRet = window.showModalDialog(url,0,'Status:NO;dialogWidth:750px;dialogHeight:500px') ;
form.field.value = strRet ;

In the modal:

window.returnValue = myValue

window.close

thanks!
Geoff

Answer (score 1):

**showModalDialog** was an IE invention.  Firefox offers a level of support for it, but most other browsers do not.  It isn't part of "regular" JavaScript but you can use **window.open()** instead... which works in all browsers.